# How to remove rows based on certain digits of the row

Tags: r

| WEEK | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 202001 | 100 |
| 202002 | 105 |
| 202101 | 100 |
| 202202 | 105 |

I want to remove the entire row if it starts with 2021. How would I do this? It is a very large df.

Comment: If `WEEK` is a number, then `df[ df$WEEK >= 2021 & df$WEEK < 2022,]`. If it is string, then `df[ grepl("^2021", df$WEEK),]`. You can also use `subset(df, WEEK >= 2021 & WEEK < 2022)` or `subset(df, grepl("^2021", WEEK))`. If you are using `dplyr`, then you can replace `subset` with `dplyr::filter`. I suggest you read [`?Extract`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) and [`?subset`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html) for help on the different methods.

Comment: We have to use `!` to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

"I want to remove the entire row if it starts with 2021".
Then we have to use `!`

```
library(dplyr)

dplyr::filter(df, !grepl("^2021",WEEK))
```

```
    WEEK Sales
1 202001   100
2 202002   105
3 202202   105
```